# Weird problem adding up elements from matrice in list

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, timing

I encountered a problem which seems very weird to me. I hope it can be understood from my description and is reproducible.

I try to add up elements of a matrice to a vector (part of FEM), an example would be this:

```
dirivekb[mat_, vek_, dirilist_, diriwerte_] := 
Module[{nnodes, maxdiri, vektorb},
vektorb = vek;
nnodes = Length[mat];
maxdiri = Length[dirilist];
For[i = 1, i <= nnodes, i++,
vektorb[[i]] = 
vektorb[[i]] - 
Sum[diriwerte[[j]]*mat[[i, dirilist[[j]]]], {j, 1, maxdiri}];
(*Print[vektorb[[i]]];*) 
];
Return[vektorb];
];

f[len_]:=(
lend=len/10.;
mat=Table[RandomReal[1],len,len];
vek=Table[RandomReal[1],len];
dirilist=Range[lend];
diriwerte=Table[RandomReal[1],lend];
AbsoluteTiming@(dirivekb[mat,vek,dirilist,diriwerte];)
)

f[2499.]
```

If I want to do this with a matrice of size 2499 time needed is 0.87 seconds. However, for a matrice of size 2500, the time consumption is huge. For that size, it would take an hour or so, since it then takes about one second per iteration in `dirivekb`, It seems the problem is the length of the `dirilist`. If I were to set

```
lend = len/20.;
```

then the threshold of the time increase would become 5000 elements. I infer that the problem occurs when more than 249 elements is operated on.

What is the reason for that and how can I fix it?

After all it's just elements being multiplied and added up. I tried to code it with `Table` and `Total`, since I thought the `Sum` would use a different method (although I wouldnt understand why) after a certain amount but the behaviour is the same.

Answer (score 6):

You are using explicit nested loops so your problem in growing exponentially. See if you get enough advantage from vectorizing:

```
dirivekb[mat_, vek_, dirilist_, diriwerte_] := 
 vek - mat[[All, dirilist]].diriwerte
```